# Firebase Multi Factor Authentication web error - auth/code-expired

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying implementing the Firebase SMS multifatcor authentication,
all the function seems to working fine, tried by consoling all the function call output,but as soon as after submitting the recaptcha , i'm entering the otp within 2 sec , but it's giving this error. this is my code please help

```
const verifyPhoneNumber = async ({
    phoneNumber,
    recaptchaVerifier,
  }) => {
    const multiFactorSession = await multiFactor(auth.currentUser).getSession();
    const phoneInfoOptions = {
      phoneNumber,
      multiFactorSession,
    };
    console.log(phoneInfoOptions)
    const phoneAuthProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth);
    try {
      return await phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneInfoOptions,
        recaptchaVerifier,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };


const setUpRecaptcha = async (phoneNumber) => {
  const recaptchaContainer = document.getElementById("recaptcha-container");
  if (recaptchaContainer) {
    try {
      const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
        auth,
        recaptchaContainer,
        {
          size: "normal",
          callback: function () {},
          "expired-callback": function () {},
        },
      );

      if (recaptchaVerifier) {
        recaptchaVerifier.render();
        const response = await verifyPhoneNumber({
          phoneNumber,
          recaptchaVerifier,
        });

        if (response) {
          recaptchaVerifier.clear();
          return response;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("got the err", e);
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

export const GetOtp = async (
  phoneNumber,
  setPhoneNumber,
  setVerificationId,
) => {
  try {
    console.log("processing..");
    const response = await setUpRecaptcha(phoneNumber);
    setVerificationId((prevVerificationId) => {
      return response;
    });
    setPhoneNumber("");
  } catch (error) {
    setPhoneNumber("");
  }
};
export const VerifyOtp = async (verificationId,otp,setPhoneVerified,setOtp,toast) => {
    try {
      const response = await enrollUser( verificationId, otp );
      if (response) {
        setPhoneVerified(true);
        setOtp("");
        toast.success("Phone is Authentiacted")
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("can't submit otp", err);
    }
  };
  const enrollUser = async (  verificationId, otp ) => {
    const phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId,
      otp
    );
    console.log(phoneAuthCredential);
    const multiFactorAssertion = PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(phoneAuthCredential);
    
    try {
      const response = await multiFactor(auth.currentUser).enroll(
        multiFactorAssertion,
        "My personal phone number"
      );
      if(response){
        return true;
      }else{
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error", e);
      return false;
    }
  };
```

I was trying to implement sms multi auth with firebase when the user sign in with google provider,
everything working fine, but when i enter the otp and verifyOtp function trigger it throws the
"firebase:auth/code-expired", even though i'm entering the otp at time span of 2 sec after getting the sms on my phone, but when i'm doing the same thing with firebase testing number it's not giving any code-expied error. please guide me